# $\sum_{r_n \le x} 2^{-n}$ is continuous on $\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$ and discontinuous on $\Bbb Q$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $\{r_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ be an enumeration of the rationals. Define $$F(x) := \sum_{r_n \le x} 2^{-n}$$
Following [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3343963/425395), I'd like to show that $F$ is discontinuous at every rational, but continuous at every irrational.

---

Here's my shot at it:

Pick $x \in \Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$ and $\epsilon > 0$. We want $\delta > 0$ such that $|y-x| < \delta$ implies $|F(y) - F(x)| < \epsilon$. Suppose $y \in (x-\delta,x)$. The condition $|F(y) - F(x)| < \epsilon$ is satisfied if and only if
$$\left|\sum_{r_n \le y} 2^{-n} - \sum_{r_n \le x} 2^{-n} \right| = \left|\sum_{y < r_n \le x} 2^{-n} \right| < \epsilon$$ I'm not sure what to do next. Could I have any hints, and intuition on why the said function behaves in such a peculiar manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote $$f_n(x)=\frac1{2^n}\chi_{[r_n, +\infty)}(x),\qquad x\in\mathbb R, n\geq1,$$
then $|f_n|\leq\frac1{2^n}$, and thus
$$F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$$
is a uniformly convergent series. For $x_0\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$, $f_n$ is continuous at $x_0$ for each $n$, hence $F$ is continuous at $x_0$. For $x_0\in\mathbb Q$, there exists $n_0$ such that $x_0=r_{n_0}$, then $f_n$ is continuous at $x_0$ for each $n\neq n_0$, hence
$$F-f_{n_0}=\sum_{n\neq n_0}f_n$$ is continuous at $x_0$; however, $f_{n_0}$ is discontinuous at $x_0$, hence $F$ is discontinuous at $x_0$.

Answer (score 2):

As $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}$ is a convergent series, for sufficiently large $N$, we must have $\sum_{n=N}^\infty 2^{-n}<\epsilon$.

Let $\delta = \min_{n=1}^N{|x-r_n|}$. If $x$ is irrational, then $\delta>0$, and we have for any $y \in (x-\delta, 0)$, if $y<r_n<x$, then $|r_n-x|<\delta$ hence $n>N$, then $$|F(x)-F(y)|= \sum_{y<r_n\le x} 2^{-n}= \sum_{y<r_n< x} 2^{-n}\le \sum_{n=N}^\infty 2^{-n}<\epsilon$$

Similarly, we can show for any $y\in (x, x+\delta)$, the equality holds as well. Therefore $F(x)$ is continuous at every irrational point.

If $x=r_N$ is rational, for any $y<x$, we must have $$|F(x)-F(y)|= F(x)-F(y)=\sum_{y< r_n \le x } 2^{-n}\ge 2^{-N}$$

no matter how close $y$ is to $x$ from the left.

However, it can be shown that $F(x)$ is right continuous everywhere (More generally this holds for any [cumulative probability distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function)).

From the proof (and in particular if you have some experience with probability density), it's easy to see that for any sequence of real numbers $\{r_1, r_2, \cdots\}$, the function $F(x)$ as defined must be continuous everywhere except at every $r_i$. This has little to do with rational or irrational numbers. In particular, $\mathbb Q$ being dense in $\mathbb R$ is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!